# Validate Repeated Exact Match Pattern with Optional Word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to read a pattern input string. Let's assume this input string is separated in each by new space.

The first numeric-string (one, two, three, ... ) is mandatory, optional numeric-string can be optional to represent up until it meets operand then comes after same numeric-string pattern.
For example,

```
ONE TWO ADD TWO FIVE // which is valid
ONE ADD TWO // which is valid
TWO SUB FIVE // also is valid
SUB TWO // is not valid
```

How can I approach using regex to find a pattern? I barely started using Java's Pattern and Matcher class to start with.

```
    public boolean validate(String inputStr) {
    // pattern regex
    /* (zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\\s(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)?\\s(add|sub) */
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\\s[(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)]?\\s(add|sub|divide|multiply)\\s(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    // input string
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputStr);

    return m.matches();
}
```

It returns false.

```
    boolean isValidate = validate("One add two ");
    System.out.println(isValidate);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when ever the optional numeric string is not present it will take the space also after that so all together it will match for twospaces after the first string which will not be there and you are getting false.So move the space also inside the square bracket.

try this,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\\s){1,2}(add|sub|divide|multiply)(\\s(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)){1,2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: This returns `false` for the first `"ONE TWO ADD TWO FIVE"`.

Comment: Yea, it returns `false` for `"ONE FIVE ADD TWO"` as well

Comment: Modified my one above.It works good and you can extend that for any number of cases.

Comment: @RKC Hey, from my question yes you are correct. I needed to be unlimited numbers before and after operand. I kind modified `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\\s){1,}(add|sub|divide|multiply)(\\s(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)){1,}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` it seems work perfect! can you verify it? thanks.

Comment: Just make '\\s' as '\\s+' in case if more than one space is given in between the strings it will not fail.